# Where can i download a GUI version of centos 7.2

Tags: linux, centos

It seems these versions are already archived. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of CentOS are stored in [the vault](https://vault.centos.org/).

[Per the CentOS wiki](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/General#How_does_CentOS_versioning_work.3F), the vault "...contains older CentOS trees. This vault is a picture of the older tree when it was removed from the main tree, and does not receive updates. It should only be used for reference."

If you want to download the 7.2 image, you can obtain it from [here](https://vault.centos.org/7.2.1511/isos/x86_64/). Choose the GUI that fits your needs.